# Who are the people standing around in Trump's office, and how much are they paid?

Tags: united-states, president

In the last several days since the inauguration, I have seen on TV and in the press many images of Donald Trump sitting at a vast table signing documents. Behind and beside him stand a coterie of smartly-dressed, important-looking people, who don't seem to be doing much except handing him documents and watching him sign.

Does anyone know who they are, what exactly their role amounts to, and how much they are being paid for standing there? Would it not be cheaper to use mannequins?

Comment: > how much they are being paid for standing there? you can find out how much they are being paid, but you have to established first that they are being paid for standing there.

Comment: Do you have an example picture? From the sound of it, it could well be just that people are invited to watch the President sign stuff (this is a common practice that is not new to the Trump administration).

Comment: This is way Too Broad and Unclear What You're Asking.  As you may have noticed many of the people change and others stay the same.  There have been at least twelve times that Trump has signed documents, and that number will only increase (Obama signed more than two thousand documents like that in his two terms).  Which event?  Which people?  We might identify a specific person from a picture, but a general answer?  Also, somewhat Opinion-based, since Obama had similar ceremonies.  Why only pick on Trump?

Comment: @Brythan Re *"pick on"*:  it's unclear in what sense such a question might be [harrassing](http://www.wordnik.com/words/pick%20on) anyone.  If the OP is merely curious about who populates certain ceremonial pictures, that curiosity should bother no one.  (Agreed that the OP needs to specify *which* pictures.)

Comment: @agc  I'm talking about "how much they are being paid for standing there? Would it not be cheaper to use mannequins?"  That is using the question to express an opinion.  The first part is fine but the second is not.

Comment: @Brythan [This is the sort of thing I mean](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/28/politics/donald-trump-executive-actions/index.html). Am I to understand that these are ordinary members of the public who have been co-opted to witness the proceedings? I had assumed they were White House staff, who were being paid to do nothing other than watch the President sign his name. Forgive me but it is all a bit foreign. In my country the Queen signs Acts of Parliament in private. And the last monarch, who actually refused to sign one was Queen Anne in 1708.

Comment: Right to left:  Stephen Miller, Policy Advisor; (no face guy unidentified); Reince Priebus, Chief of Staff; Katie Walsh, Deputy Chief of Staff; Kellyanne Conway; I forget the last guy's name, but I've seen him on news shows.  [Political appointees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_appointments_of_Donald_Trump).  And of course Trump is the guy in front doing the signing.

Answer (score 3):

Presidential document signings  (ie Bills, or in this cases likely executive orders) are frequently big press events. As such people want to be in the picture in order to be associated as a key played in the event. This is generally for just cause as they tend to be people who were directly involved in the creation of the

The exact people in the picture depend event to event, but some common players you'll find are:

[image]

[Mike Pence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Pence), Trump's Vice President

[image]

[Reince Priebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reince_Priebus), Trump's Chief of staff

[image]

[Paul Ryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Ryan), the speaker of the house

[image]

[Steve Bannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Bannon), one of Trump's very close aides

As these people are all public servants you can Google their salaries. Despite the snarky wording of your question, they aren't being paid to stand there, they are simply celebrating their success (as is standard pretty much everywhere).

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. Perfectly reasonable and non-controversial answer.

Comment: Re *"they aren't being paid to stand there"*: if those signings occur during those public servants' working hours, then it constitutes ceremonial duty, so in a sense they are being paid to stand there.

Comment: @agc Not really. At your job when you stand at the water fountain are you being paid to stand at the water fountain? No. When someone has a birthday and you celebrate at lunch are you being paid to celebrate birthdays? When you finish a big project and your team goes to celebrate... you get the point. Some things are just part of your work life. That doesn't mean its what you're being paid for.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, unlike wholly or relatively private affairs such as water fountains, birthday parties, or private sector work parties, a public government ceremonial photo-op is meant not just to be experienced by those directly involved, but to be widely seen and made as memorable as the occasion organizer's aspirations can manage.  One question to distinguish public ceremonies from private is: would they do that if nobody was looking?   Water fountain standers -- yes.   Officials awed by their superior's penmanship -- probably not.